# How do I make my Microchip MPLAB X IDE project use the free version of the XC32 compiler?

Tags: microchip, mplabx

I was previously compiling my C and C++ PIC32 mcu project in Microchip's MPLAB X IDE v6.15 with a paid Pro XC32 compiler license. My license has expired and [no amount of buying a new one will fix it](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/695730/26234), so meanwhile I'd like to compile with the free license.

On Linux Ubuntu 22.04, I reinstalled the license, but this time chose the "Free" option at the end of the installer process, and yet the compiler is still complaining about the license being gone.

Everything on the Microchip website indicates that the free compiler should work just fine: https://www.microchip.com/en-us/tools-resources/develop/mplab-xc-compilers# (emphasis added):

> Are you looking for code optimizations? Our **free** MPLAB XC C Compiler comes with the majority of the optimizations you need to reduce your code size and increase its efficiency. If you're unsure which optimizations are best for your design, our **free** MPLAB XC Compiler Advisor can help you find the best optimizations for your project. Specifically, **the free compiler contains these optimizations:**
>
> - O0 - Ensures that your code is in its pristine state
> - O1 - Invokes all optimizations that won't affect debugging
> - O2 - Invokes a balanced set of speed and size optimizations
>
> When you purchase one of our PRO licenses, you also get the following optimizations:
>
> - Os - Gives maximum code size reductions
> - O3 - Gives the best speed optimizations
> - mpa (Procedural Abstraction) - Reduces code size even further

My gcc optimization level is set to `1`:

[image]

And my g++ optimization level is also `1`:

[image]

Yet, I still get this error when building:

> Subscription License has not been renewed - the activation server "http://keyverify.microchip.com" gave the unexpected result -160
>
> License has expired

So, what project settings do I need to change to make it build with the free compiler?

Note that at one point I also tried deleting my license file at `/opt/microchip/xclm/license/microchip-1.lic`, but I got the same result. (Though maybe I needed to close and reopen the project, not just the IDE?)

It's possible I'm misunderstanding the license. Is it free only for C, not C++ projects? I can't find that documented anywhere though.

---

Note: If anyone in the community wants to work on using a free, GPL, non-paid XC32 compiler, join me here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/Microchip_XC32_Compiler

Comment: Per your linked post from your other question, I offer the same advice: contact Microchip. What is the hesitancy? I used to work with Microchip on a regular basis. They provide excellent support.

Comment: @C__, as I mentioned at the bottom of my other answer: I've opened a support ticket, emailed, posted on the forum, and called, for three days now, and have reached nobody. This is blocking my professional work so I'm looking at all options.

Comment: Also, this is a generic question that applies to anyone regardless of my particular circumstance: how do you use the free compiler?

Comment: Truthfully this sounds like a software issue. My best recommendation is to backup your projects, uninstall and reinstall the software with the free usage license, and make sure you don't have any configuration files that the software claims that you once had the premium license. I'm sure there's a file somewhere that says that you once had a premium license.

Comment: That could be it.

Comment: [View Compiler FAQs](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/DEV/ProductDocuments/Brochures/Compiler-FAQs-00004665.pdf) contains ``The license file will allow compiling with your chosen optimization options from -O1 -O2 -O3 or -Os.``. Does that mean with the free compiler the optimization level must be set to ``O0`` (i.e. no optimization)?

Comment: @ChesterGillon, great find, but no luck. :(  I changed to optimization level `-O0`, both via the menus and explicitly in the `Additional options` box, and it didn't work. To be sure, I also deleted the license file, closed the project, closed the IDE, deleted all build files and `myProject.X/nbproject/Makefile-*` autogenerated makefiles, manually called `prjMakefilesGenerator myProject.X` to rebuild the build files, re-opened the IDE, re-opened the project, & tried to build again. No luck. With the license file deleted though now, the new error is `error: MPLAB XC32 C++ license not activated`.

Comment: Have you tried this link: https://www.microchip.com/xcdemo/xcpluspromo2.aspx?id=step2

Comment: @Rodo, that's it! Thank you so much! How did you find that link anyway? I searched all over the internet and the Microchip website and never came across that link, unfortunately. Perhaps the latest compilers don't require that step? I'm not 100% sure, because my huge mixed C and C++ project is on an old XC32 compiler version, and the only work I've done with the latest 4.35 compiler is some hello world type projects in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@Rodo's link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/695789/how-do-i-make-my-microchip-mplab-x-ide-project-use-the-free-version-of-the-xc32?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1853082_695789) works!--so long as the Microchip license server is up (it's been down the last two weeks or so at the end of 2023, but is up as of 2 Jan. 2024).

Setup notes:

*Tested in Linux Ubuntu 22.04 with MPLAB X IDE v6.15 and XC32 compiler v1.42 (very old) and v4.35 (the latest version).*

- I expect this process would also work fine in Windows and MacOS, with slightly different commands is all.
- To use Git in Windows, you'll need to install [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) and run all Linux-like commands inside the MSYS2-based *Git Bash* terminal. My personal [Git For Windows installation instructions are here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/issues/27#issue-1950880578).
- To run build commands in Windows at the command-line, and/or get access to other Linux tools installed by the `pacman` package manager, you'll need MSYS2. See my instructions here: [Installing & setting up MSYS2 from scratch, including adding all 7 profiles to Windows Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77407282/4561887).

### How to install the free XC32++ compiler license (including `.gitignore` setup and refreshing the project)

### Shorter summary

1. Download and install the latest MPLAB X IDE: https://www.microchip.com/en-us/tools-resources/develop/mplab-x-ide

   The latest at the time of this writing is v6.15.

   The latest IDEs work with even the oldest XC32 compilers and do not affect compilation output.
2. Download and install the XC32 compiler of your choice: https://www.microchip.com/en-us/tools-resources/develop/mplab-xc-compilers/xc32

   Use whatever your project or company requires. Even old compilers such as v1.42 work fine with the latest IDEs and the free license below.

   The latest XC32 compiler at the time of this writing is v4.35.
3. Download and install a free XC32 compiler license: https://www.microchip.com/xcdemo/xcpluspromo2.aspx?id=step2

   For the "Your MAC Address" box, enter the "Host id" as shown in the output of `xclm -hostinfo`. On Linux and Mac, run that in the terminal. On Windows, run that in the Command Prompt (cmd.exe) or in the Git Bash terminal. This `xclm` XC32 Compiler License Manager command-line tool was installed for you when you installed the XC32 compiler above.

   The "Host id" shown by that command is the same as:

   1. On Linux: the first MAC address (with*out* any colons) shown in the output of `ip link show | grep ether`.
   2. On Windows: one of the MAC addresses (it seems to change on me) shown in the output of `ipconfig /all | findstr "Physical Address"`, when run in the Command Prompt (cmd.exe).

   If you use the wrong host ID, the license will fail to work in the end and you'll get this error when you try to build:

   ```
   error: MPLAB XC32 C++ license not activated
   ```
4. With the MPLAB X IDE, XC32 compiler, and a free compiler license all installed, you can now compile C or C++ in the IDE up to optimization level `-O1` without any warnings or issues.

   There are no program size constraints with the free compiler license.

   For full support of optimization levels > `-O1`, you'll need to buy a pro license [or compile a license-free version of the XC32 compiler from source yourself](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/Microchip_XC32_Compiler).

   1. Pro licenses are here; there are various options: https://www.microchip.com/en-us/tools-resources/develop/mplab-xc-compilers/licenses.

      1. The subscription license is probably the cheapest, at < $50/month, and is what I use. But, if the license renewal server is down and it's time for your license to auto-renew, you may lose your ability to compile for days or weeks, [which has happened to me](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/695730/26234). Get it here: https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tool/SW006023-SUB.

### More details, and screenshots

1. Ensure you have downloaded and installed the MPLAB X IDE and an XC32 compiler. Once you have extracted the compiler down to a `.run` file, such as `xc32-v4.35-full-install-linux-x64-installer.run`, the installation command in Linux looks like this:

   ```bash
   chmod +x xc32-v4.35-full-install-linux-x64-installer.run
   sudo ./xc32-v4.35-full-install-linux-x64-installer.run
   ```

   During the install, you'll see this window where you get to choose the "Free" license option. In my experience (perhaps just with their older XC32 compilers, since I'm using an older version actually), this selection does absolutely nothing and means absolutely nothing:

   [image]

   When the installer completes, you can confirm you have no free license whatsoever by looking in the `/opt/microchip/xclm/license` dir. A free license would be here: `/opt/microchip/xclm/license/xc32fpp-1.lic`.

   Note: here are the license directory paths for all three main OSs:

   - Windows - `%SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microchip\xclm\license`
   - Mac - `/Library/Application\ Support/microchip/xclm/license`
   - Linux - `/opt/microchip/xclm/license`

   You can also find the license path by running this command:

   ```bash
   xclm -licensepath
   ```

   The generic help menu can be shown like this, but I don't know how to use the other commands nor what they're useful for, yet:

   ```bash
   xclm
   ```

   If you try to build, you may see this:

   ```
   main.cpp:1:0: note: Visit http://www.microchip.com/MPLABXCcompilers to acquire a free C++ license
   make[0]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-MY_PROJECT.mk:3943: build/MY_PROJECT/production/_ext/935690222/my_file.o] Error 255
   another_file.cpp:1:0: error: MPLAB XC32 C++ license not activated
   ```

   **You have no "activated" free license!**
2. So, [as @Rodo said](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/695789/how-do-i-make-my-microchip-mplab-x-ide-project-use-the-free-version-of-the-xc32?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1853082_695789), go here to download a free license!: https://www.microchip.com/xcdemo/xcpluspromo2.aspx?id=step2. Use that link exactly. The `?id=step2` part at the end is required.

   You'll see this: [image].

   In the "Your MAC Address" box, enter the MAC address (with*out* any colons) shown in the first line of the output of this command:

   ```bash
   ip link show | grep ether
   ```

   So, if your output looks like this:

   ```
   $ ip link show | grep ether
   link/ether 01:02:03:04:05:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   link/ether 0c:0b:0a:09:08:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   link/ether 0d:0e:0f:1a:1b:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   ```

   ...then the MAC address you should enter is: `010203040506`.

   You can confirm this by running this command:

   ```bash
   xclm -hostinfo
   ```

   where `xclm` is the XC32 License Manager executable that is now installed on your system since you ran the XC32 compiler installer above. `which xclm` shows that it is located in `/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.35/bin/xclm`, for instance.

   The output of `xclm -hostinfo` looks like this. Notice that the "host id" is the same as the MAC address we entered above:

   ```bash
   Host id is:
   010203040506
   Host name is:
   gabriel-my-computer
   ```

   Then, choose your OS from the dropdown and click the `Get free XC32++ license` button.

   Microchip's license server will make a custom free license for you, so long as it is working. I has been down for several weeks at the end of 2023/beginning of 2024, hence [my question here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/695730/26234). I don't know if this https://www.microchip.com/xcdemo/xcpluspromo2.aspx?id=step2 link worked during that time.

   You'll now get to download a file called `cpluslic.sh`, for instance.
3. Install the license.

   On Linux, the commands are:

   ```bash
   chmod +x cpluslic.sh
   ./cpluslic.sh
   ```

   You'll see this output:

   ```
   Detected operating system: Linux

   Creating license file /opt/microchip/xclm/license/xc32fpp-1.lic
   ```

   You'll now see a license file at `/opt/microchip/xclm/license/xc32fpp-1.lic`.

   Notes:

   1. Running this `.sh` license installer will fail if you haven't installed an XC32 compiler yet. The license installer looks for the existence of the `/opt/microchip/xclm/license` dir to see if you have the compiler installed, and fails if that directory doesn't exist.
   2. If you open your installed license file in a text editor (ex: run `code /opt/microchip/xclm/license/xc32fpp-1.lic` to open it in MS VSCode), you'll see the words `permanent uncounted` in it, which means that this free license *never* expires! That's great! If it expires, you'll see an expiration date there instead, such as this: `27-dec-2023 uncounted`. In my paid, monthly-subscription Pro licenses, they expire every month. That full line in the license file looks like this (expires 27 Dec. 2023 in this case):

      ```
      LICENSE microchip swxc32-cpp 1.0 27-dec-2023 uncounted
      ```

      or this (never expires):

      ```
      LICENSE microchip swxc32-fpp 1.1 permanent uncounted
      ```
   3. My experimentation shows that:

      1. The name of the license file doesn't really matter, so you can rename them to help you keep track of your licenses. Ex: here I have added `_free` and `_pro` to the end of my default license file names so I can remember which is which: all inside the `/opt/microchip/xclm/license` dir:

         ```bash
         microchip-1_pro.lic  # my old, expired XC32 Pro license
         microchip-2_pro.lic  # my new, valid XC32 Pro license I just installed!
         xc32fpp-1_free.lic   # my FREE XC32 license I installed as a work-around
         ```
      2. You can have multiple licenses installed at once, but if a pro license exists, the IDE will try to use the latest pro license *even if it is expired*. So, to force your free license to be used instead, move all pro licenses out of the license directory.
      3. If multiple pro licenses are installed, the latest one will be used, so there is no need to delete old pro licenses as you renew and install new pro licenses. For more on this, see my answer here: [How to renew your paid Microchip XC32 Compiler Pro license when it has expired or is about to expire](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/695772/26234).
4. Refresh the project in the IDE, and delete auto-generated content that should be ignored.

   *Note: I don't know if this part is strictly required here, but I've found that in `git checkout`s the MPLAB X IDE and the configuration files frequently get out of sync, as the IDE only reads the project config files at certain times, and it uses and writes back old/stale/wrong data if you don't do this. So, it's not a bad idea to do this after any `git checkout` which modifies the project configuration file, or whenever making big settings changes such as to license files.*

   Close your project in the IDE (right-click it --> Close), then close the IDE.

   Manually delete all auto-generated content and build files, and commit the change to `git`:

   ```bash
   cd MyProject.X
   rm -r \
       .generated_files/ \
       build/ \
       dist/ \
       nbproject/Makefile-* \
       nbproject/Package-* \
       nbproject/private/ \
       private/ \
       debug/
   git add -A
   git commit -m "Remove auto-generated files"
   ```

   Run `prjMakefilesGenerator MyProject.X` to regenerate the build files. I have `prjMakefilesGenerator` as a symlink (in my PATH) pointing to `/opt/microchip/mplabx/v6.15/mplab_platform/bin/prjMakefilesGenerator.sh`. If you don't, run it explicitly instead:

   ```bash
   /opt/microchip/mplabx/v6.15/mplab_platform/bin/prjMakefilesGenerator.sh path/to/MyProject.X
   ```

   Then, re-open the IDE, and reopen the `MyProject.X` project directory.

   **Additional notes:**

   1. To properly ignore the auto-generated files, add this to your `.gitignore` file too. From [my `.gitignore` file for MPLAB X IDE projects here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_MPLABX/blob/main/.gitignore):

      ```bash
      # MPLAB X Generated Project Files
      .generated_files/
      build/
      dist/
      **/nbproject/Makefile-*
      **/nbproject/Package-*
      **/nbproject/private/
      private/
      ```
   2. Once you've manually deleted the above files once *and* committed this change to git, *and* you have created the `.gitignore` file with the contents above, you can forcefully remove all ignored files next time with my [`git-rm_ignored_files.sh`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/git-rm_ignored_files.sh) script from my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) repo. It calls `git clean -Xdn` and `git clean -Xdf` which do this.
5. (Optional) View your license in the MPLAB X IDE via Tools --> Licenses --> Change Licensing Type.
6. Voilà! You can now compile!

   Click the little arrow to the right of this button here:

   [image]

   And select "Clean and Build", as shown here:

   [image]

   In the build output window at the bottom-right of the IDE, you'll see `CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 51ms)` in green at the top of the build output. Several seconds (or dozens of seconds for large projects) later, you'll see this at the bottom of the build output, with the `BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9s)` part in green:

   ```
   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9s)
   Loading code from /home/gabriel/GS/dev/my_repo/MyProject.X/dist/default/production/MyProject.X.production.hex...
   Program loaded with pack,PIC32MZ-EF_DFP,1.3.58,Microchip
   Loading completed
   ```

   The build was successful!

   This free license file appears to work on *any* version of the XC32 compiler, including very old versions such as XC32 v1.42, as well as the newest versions such as v4.35, which is currently the latest.

   The free license works perfectly fine, for both C and C++, even with optimization level `-O1` set for both of them. Using higher optimization levels than that will still build successfully, but will produce a warning that "Optimization level > 1" is ignored and not supported by the free license version of the compiler. See my test results below. Therefore, for full support of optimization levels > `-O1`, you'll need to buy a pro license [or compile a license-free version of the XC32 compiler from source yourself](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/Microchip_XC32_Compiler).

*You can stop reading here if that's all you needed.*

---

### Testing compiler optimization levels with the free compiler license

My microcontroller has:

- RAM: 512 KiB
- Flash: 2 MiB

I tested all optimization levels with the free compiler, using XC32 version 1.42 (I know, very old), setting the optimization level in both the `xc32-gcc` *and* `xc32-g++` settings at the same time. See screenshots in the question for these settings. Get my [`size_mcu`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/size_mcu.sh) script to run on the `.elf` firmware files from my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) repo.

The `xc32-size` executable is located at `/opt/microchip/xc32/v1.42/bin/xc32-size`.

Here are the results with the free compiler, to see which optimization levels it accepts and how this affects the build size:

1. `-O0` - builds successfully

   1. Size reported in the bottom-left GUI window in the IDE:

      1. Data Used: 480190 bytes (92%)
      2. Program Used: 1739476 bytes (83%)
   2. Size reported by my `size_mcu` script:

      ```
      $ size_mcu xc32-size MyProject.X/dist/default/production/MyProject.X.production.elf --flash 2097152 --ram 524288
      size_info = 'xc32-size MyProject.X/dist/default/production/MyProject.X.production.elf' = 

      text     rodata    data     bss     dec     hex filename
      1242536  496964   16789  464225 2220514  21e1e2 MyProject.X/dist/default/production/MyProject.X.production.elf

      FLASH used . . . . . . . . .  = 1756289 bytes ( 83.746%). Remaining is  340863 bytes ( 16.254%). . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  Max is 2097152 bytes.
      SRAM used by global variables =   16789 bytes (  3.202%). Remaining is  507499 bytes ( 96.798%) for local (stack) variables or RTOS stack & heap. Max is  524288 bytes.
      ```
2. `-O1` - builds successfully

   1. Size reported in the bottom-left GUI window in the IDE:

      1. Data Used: 478878 bytes (91%)
      2. Program Used: 1283428 bytes (61%)
   2. Size reported by my `size_mcu` script:

      ```
      $ size_mcu xc32-size MyProject.X/dist/default/production/MyProject.X.production.elf --flash 2097152 --ram 524288
      size_info = 'xc32-size MyProject.X/dist/default/production/MyProject.X.production.elf' = 

      text     rodata    data     bss     dec     hex filename
      789524   493928   15709  463993 1763154  1ae752 MyProject.X/dist/default/production/MyProject.X.production.elf

      FLASH used . . . . . . . . .  = 1299161 bytes ( 61.949%). Remaining is  797991 bytes ( 38.051%). . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  Max is 2097152 bytes.
      SRAM used by global variables =   15709 bytes (  2.996%). Remaining is  508579 bytes ( 97.004%) for local (stack) variables or RTOS stack & heap. Max is  524288 bytes.
      ```
3. `-O2` - ignores the option and builds successfully at *approximately* the `O1` level; produces the following warning while compiling:

   ```
   main.c:1:0: warning: Compiler option (Optimization level > 1) ignored 
   because the free XC32 C compiler does not support this feature. 
   [enabled by default]
   //
   ^
   cc1: note: Disable the option or visit 
   http://www.microchip.com/MPLABXCcompilers to purchase a new MPLAB XC 
   compiler license.
   ```

   Notice that in the size results below, the "Data Used" is exactly identical to the `O1` results above, but the "Program Used" is slightly larger. Also, comparing the `O1` and `O2` hex files using `meld` shows that they differ significantly. So, I don't know what the compiler is doing here, but it's definitely not `O2`, and is not *quite* the same thing as `O1`!

   1. Size reported in the bottom-left GUI window in the IDE:

      1. Data Used: 478878 bytes (91%)
      2. Program Used: 1288296 bytes (61%)
   2. Size reported by my `size_mcu` script:

      ```
      $ size_mcu xc32-size MyProject.X/dist/default/production/MyProject.X.production.elf --flash 2097152 --ram 524288
      size_info = 'xc32-size MyProject.X/dist/default/production/MyProject.X.production.elf' = 

      text     rodata    data     bss     dec     hex filename
      794372   493948   15709  463993 1768022  1afa56 MyProject.X/dist/default/production/MyProject.X.production.elf

      FLASH used . . . . . . . . .  = 1304029 bytes ( 62.181%). Remaining is  793123 bytes ( 37.819%). . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  Max is 2097152 bytes.
      SRAM used by global variables =   15709 bytes (  2.996%). Remaining is  508579 bytes ( 97.004%) for local (stack) variables or RTOS stack & heap. Max is  524288 bytes.
      ```
4. `-O3` - ignores the option and builds successfully at *approximately* the `O1` level. It produces the same warning as the `-O2` option above, and its size results differ slightly from both the `-O1` and `-O2` options above.

   Same type of warning:

   ```
   main.c:1:0: warning: Compiler option (Optimization level > 1) ignored 
   because the free XC32 C compiler does not support this feature. 
   [enabled by default]
   //
   ^
   cc1: note: Disable the option or visit 
   http://www.microchip.com/MPLABXCcompilers to purchase a new MPLAB XC 
   compiler license.
   ```

   1. Size reported in the bottom-left GUI window in the IDE:

      1. Data Used: 478874 bytes (91%)
      2. Program Used: 1288072 bytes (61%)
   2. Size reported by my `size_mcu` script:

      ```
      $ size_mcu xc32-size MyProject.X/dist/default/production/MyProject.X.production.elf --flash 2097152 --ram 524288
      size_info = 'xc32-size MyProject.X/dist/default/production/MyProject.X.production.elf' = 

      text     rodata    data     bss     dec     hex filename
      794148   493948   15709  463989 1767794  1af972 MyProject.X/dist/default/production/MyProject.X.production.elf

      FLASH used . . . . . . . . .  = 1303805 bytes ( 62.170%). Remaining is  793347 bytes ( 37.830%). . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  Max is 2097152 bytes.
      SRAM used by global variables =   15709 bytes (  2.996%). Remaining is  508579 bytes ( 97.004%) for local (stack) variables or RTOS stack & heap. Max is  524288 bytes.
      ```
5. `-Os` - ignores the option and builds successfully at *approximately* the `O1` level, but a tiny bit smaller in program space. It produces the same warning as the `-O2` and `-O3` options above, and its size results differ slightly from both the `-O1` and `-O2` options above.

   Same type of warning:

   ```
   main.c:1:0: warning: Compiler option (Optimization level > 1) ignored 
   because the free XC32 C compiler does not support this feature. 
   [enabled by default]
   //
   ^
   cc1: note: Disable the option or visit 
   http://www.microchip.com/MPLABXCcompilers to purchase a new MPLAB XC 
   compiler license.
   ```

   1. Size reported in the bottom-left GUI window in the IDE:

      1. Data Used: 478878 bytes (91%)
      2. Program Used: 1244452 bytes (59%)
   2. Size reported by my `size_mcu` script:

      ```
      $ size_mcu xc32-size MyProject.X/dist/default/production/MyProject.X.production.elf --flash 2097152 --ram 524288
      size_info = 'xc32-size MyProject.X/dist/default/production/MyProject.X.production.elf' = 

      text     rodata    data     bss     dec     hex filename
      750360   494116   15709  463993 1724178  1a4f12 MyProject.X/dist/default/production/MyProject.X.production.elf

      FLASH used . . . . . . . . .  = 1260185 bytes ( 60.090%). Remaining is  836967 bytes ( 39.910%). . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  Max is 2097152 bytes.
      SRAM used by global variables =   15709 bytes (  2.996%). Remaining is  508579 bytes ( 97.004%) for local (stack) variables or RTOS stack & heap. Max is  524288 bytes.
      ```
6. [Several days later, once my Pro license was active again] As a comparison to the *real* `-Os` optimization level with a functional Pro license, here is the output. You can see that the size program size shrunk another 2~3%, so `-Os` is fully functioning now with the Pro license:

   No warnings.

   1. Size reported in the bottom-left GUI window in the IDE:

      1. Data Used: 478886 bytes (91%)
      2. Program Used: 1184936 bytes (57%)
   2. Size reported by my `size_mcu` script:

      ```
      $ size_mcu xc32-size MyProject.X/dist/default/production/MyProject.X.production.elf --flash 2097152 --ram 524288
      size_info = 'xc32-size MyProject.X/dist/default/production/MyProject.X.production.elf' = 

      text     rodata    data     bss     dec     hex filename
      690048   494912   15709  464001 1664670  19669e MyProject.X/dist/default/production/MyProject.X.production.elf

      FLASH used . . . . . . . . .  = 1200669 bytes ( 57.252%). Remaining is  896483 bytes ( 42.748%). . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  Max is 2097152 bytes.
      SRAM used by global variables =   15709 bytes (  2.996%). Remaining is  508579 bytes ( 97.004%) for local (stack) variables or RTOS stack & heap. Max is  524288 bytes.
      ```

### Final comments: PIC32 vs STM32 tools

I've found Microchip's IDE, software, configurations, compiler, licenses, support libraries and packages, and GUI configuration tools for microcontroller peripherals to be more irritating, difficult to use, and buggy than ST's comparable tools. Part of that is probably because Microchip's MPLAB X IDE is based on Netbeans instead of Eclipse.

Microchip's MPLAB X IDE is cross-platform (Windows, Mac, and Linux), and Netbeans-based. It feels a bit outdated. Their compiler is GCC-based, but locked out with paid licenses which have been integrated into the GPL source code (which is 100% legal and fine in that regard, but irritating). Their license fees are onerous and their license server flaky, costing me days of paid development time. I have built the full XC32 compiler suite royalty-free from source on both Windows and Linux, but have not integrated it for use yet. Feel free to compile it yourself and join the effort to have a royalty-free open source XC32 compiler for PIC32 mcus. Here's my repo: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/Microchip_XC32_Compiler. See the open issues.

I still have much to learn about PIC32, but after my many trials with the MPLAB X IDE glitches and quirks, and with my extensive problems with the XC32 compiler licenses, my recommendation is currently this: for anyone looking for a general-purpose high-end microcontroller, I therefore definitely recommend **STM32** ARM-core over PIC32. ST's tools are much better and easier to use. STM32CubeIDE is better, their STM32CubeMX code generator is better, and their support libraries are easier to find and use. Also, all STM32Cube libraries are on GitHub too! See here for the STM32F* chips: https://github.com/orgs/STMicroelectronics/repositories?q=stm32cubeF&type=all&language=&sort=name, and here for the STM32H* chips: https://github.com/orgs/STMicroelectronics/repositories?q=stm32cubeh&type=all&language=&sort=name.

ST's STM32CubeIDE is also cross-platform (Windows, Mac, Linux), and is Eclipse-based, which is better I think. Last I checked, all of ST's software and compiler tools are also royalty-free (no cost) and open source, which is great. No license server problems and lost development time when they are down, and no extra costs.

Having said all that, Arduino is amazing, and I love the simplicity and power of Atmel AVR chips. And, Microchip now makes them all. :) When it comes to PIC32 vs STM32, however, I'm currently leaning towards STM32, but I still have much to learn about both.

### See also

1. My Q&A: [How to renew your paid Microchip XC32 Compiler Pro license when it has expired or is about to expire](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/695772/26234)
2. My question: [How do I find out at compile time how much of an STM32's Flash memory and dynamic memory (SRAM) is used up?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/363931/26234)

   1. [My long answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/523439/26234)
   2. My [Script/command to auto-calculate Flash and SRAM usage for you](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/598163/26234)

Comment: Totally agree with the final comments and I've came to the same conclusions over the years of sometimes very painful experience.